# VMware Workstation 12 PlayerでXUbuntu15.04がユニティモードに切り替えられない

Tags: windows, vmware

Windows 10でVMware Workstation 12 Playerを利用し始めたのですが、Windows 8ではXUbuntu 15.04をユニティモードで使用できたと思うのですが、現状ユニティモードに切り替えることができない状況です。
ユニティモードに切り替えようとすると以下のエラーメッセージが出ます。

> ユニティはLinuxゲストではサポートされません。
>   ゲストOSの解像度が変更できません

インストール自体は上手くいっているようで、ファイルの共有はできるのですが、クリップボードの共有や解像度の変更ができない状況です。
解決策などありましたらよろしくお願いします。

<sub>（編注：以下、長すぎるのでコードブロックにしましたが、引用として貼り付けられていたために改行が崩れているようです。）</sub>

```
Installing VMware Tools.

In which directory do you want to install the binary files? 
[/usr/bin]  What is the directory that contains the init directories
(rc0.d/ to rc6.d/)?  [/etc]  What is the directory that contains the
init scripts?  [/etc/init.d]  In which directory do you want to
install the daemon files?  [/usr/sbin]  In which directory do you want
to install the library files?  [/usr/lib/vmware-tools]  The path
"/usr/lib/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program is 
going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this what
you want? [yes]  In which directory do you want to install the
documentation files?  [/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools]  The path
"/usr/share/doc/vmware-tools" does not exist currently. This program 
is going to create it, including needed parent directories. Is this
what you  want? [yes]  The installation of VMware Tools 10.0.0
build-2977863 for Linux completed  successfully. You can decide to
remove this software from your system at any  time by invoking the
following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-uninstall-tools.pl".

Before running VMware Tools for the first time, you need to configure
it by  invoking the following command:
"/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl". Do you want  this program to invoke
the command for you now? [yes]  The file /usr/bin/vmware-hgfsclient
that this program was about to install  already exists.  Overwrite?
[no]  Initializing...


Making sure services for VMware Tools are stopped.

Stopping Thinprint services in the virtual machine:    Stopping
Virtual Printing daemon:                                   done
Stopping VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:    VMware User
Agent (vmware-user):                                    done   
Unmounting HGFS shares:                                            
done    Guest filesystem driver:                                      
done


update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported;
falling back to defaults update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions
are no longer supported; falling back to defaults The module vmci has
already been installed on this system by another installer  or package
and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vsock has already been installed on this system by another
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vmxnet3 has already been installed on this system by
another  installer or package and will not be modified by this
installer.

The module pvscsi has already been installed on this system by another
installer or package and will not be modified by this installer.

The module vmmemctl has already been installed on this system by
another  installer or package and will not be modified by this
installer.

The VMware Host-Guest Filesystem allows for shared folders between the
host OS  and the guest OS in a Fusion or Workstation virtual
environment.  Do you wish  to enable this feature? [yes] 

Before you can compile modules, you need to have the following
installed... 

make gcc kernel headers of the running kernel


Searching for GCC... Detected GCC binary at "/usr/bin/gcc". The path
"/usr/bin/gcc" appears to be a valid path to the gcc binary. Would you
like to change it? [no]  Searching for a valid kernel header path...
Detected the kernel headers at
"/lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/build/include". The path
"/lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/build/include" appears to be a valid 
path to the 3.19.0-26-generic kernel headers. Would you like to change
it? [no]  make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only'
Using kernel build system. /usr/bin/make -C
/lib/modules/3.19.0-26-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD
SRCROOT=$PWD/. \   MODULEBUILDDIR= modules make[1]: Entering directory
'/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic'   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/message.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/dir.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/rpcout.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/filesystem.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/request.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/cpName.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/module.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/stubs.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/hgfsUtil.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/link.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/bdhandler.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/transport.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/inode.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/file.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/super.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/fsutil.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLinux.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/hgfsBd.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/backdoorGcc64.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/page.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/backdoor.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/hgfsEscape.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/dentry.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/cpNameLite.o   CC [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/kernelStubsLinux.o   LD [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.o   Building modules, stage
2.   MODPOST 1 modules   CC      /tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.mod.o   LD [M] 
/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only/vmhgfs.ko make[1]: Leaving directory
'/usr/src/linux-headers-3.19.0-26-generic' /usr/bin/make -C $PWD
SRCROOT=$PWD/. \   MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild make[1]: Entering
directory '/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only' make[1]: 'postbuild' is
up to date. make[1]: Leaving directory
'/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only' cp -f vmhgfs.ko ./../vmhgfs.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-3YWU4U/vmhgfs-only'

The vmxnet driver is no longer supported on kernels 3.3 and greater.
Please  upgrade to a newer virtual NIC. (e.g., vmxnet3 or e1000e)

VMware automatic kernel modules enables automatic building and
installation of VMware kernel modules at boot that are not already
present. This feature can be enabled/disabled by re-running
vmware-config-tools.pl.

Would you like to enable VMware automatic kernel modules? [no] 
Thinprint provides driver-free printing. Do you wish to enable this
feature?  [yes] 


Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel. update-initramfs:
Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-26-generic    Starting Virtual
Printing daemon:                                   done    Checking
acpi hot plug                                              done
Starting VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:    Switching to
guest configuration:                                   done    Guest
filesystem driver:                                            done   
Mounting HGFS shares:                                              
done The configuration of VMware Tools 10.0.0 build-2977863 for Linux
for this  running kernel completed successfully.

Enjoy,

--the VMware team
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pubs.vmware.com/Release_Notes/en/workstation/12pro/workstation-12-release-notes.html
を見ると

> The following features have reached end of life in Workstation 12 Pro and have been removed:
>   - Unity mode on Linux guest and host operating systems

という記載があります。

Worktation 12 Proからは無理なのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。VMware Player 7では利用可能なようなので探します。